# Auto-resizing a selectMenu based on item selected in primefaces

Tags: javascript, css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a selecitems list in primefaces but some of the options are a set of string characters and are longer than others. Is there a way to resize the options menu in primefaces like in this example?

```
<f:selectItems id="selectIC" value="#{createOrderBean.all}" var="tp"
                            itemLabel="#{tp.SCcode}" itemValue="#{tp}" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FSsG8/444/

Comment: This question is confusing. Are you using PrimeFaces `<p:selectOneMenu>` or standard JSF `<h:selectOneMenu>`? You keep talking about PrimeFaces, but the PrimeFaces one by default already does exactly the task you want. The standard JSF one indeed not.

Comment: hey thanks. I am talking about primefaces. I am using the advanced example from here http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml but I have longer text and it keeps overflowing once a section is selected